# gnome terminal: how to enable menu bar by default permanently

Tags: terminal, menu

I updated recently to fedora 31 and lost menu bar in gnome-terminal.

I can enable menu bar for a single terminal session by right mouse press->enable menu bar. But there is no option to enable it permanently.

I already found: [Gnome Help](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/stable/pref-menubar.html.en)

But there is no option `Show menubar by default in new terminals.` as described in the help. On older installation I see the entry as the first item in the window which I attached a screen shot.
[image: config window]

Which config file stores the terminal config? Can it be edit by hand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that a more general setting was colliding with the application specific setting. No idea why a specific setting can never override a global setting as in nearly all other options for gnome, but this is another discussion...

OK, the solution was:

start `dconf-editor`, go to `org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Settings:headerbar` and set the value to `false`. The gnome-shell must be restarted to let the new setting take effect! No idea why this is the case, but all these options are looking curious to me.

Now you can edit with right click inside a gnome-terminal session, go to Preferences->General and select "Show menubar by default in new terminals"
This menu was not visible before! This option works immediately. Not another reboot needed :-)

There is no hint in the docs for now! So I leave this answer if someone else runs in the same trouble.